# Help diagnosing a subversion error

Tags: svn, apache, hosting

My site was down today for about an hour while my host was doing some updates to the box I am on. the updates were a PostgreSQL update, Apache Recompilation, and Cpanel update.

After the updates were finished up I am getting this error from any SVN commands.

svn: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I don't know where to begin. I imagine I'll have to re-configure the svn install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling libpq ?

Also this might be helpful:http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2009-06/0199.shtml

Comment: Thanks jetru I read that earlier. Same exact issue. 

So I need to rebuild apr-util without postgre support as I'm not using it, Or rebuild it with the new libpq.so dependencies. 

I am pretty green on linux sysadmin so I could use some help. Can I just run the apr-util configure script again with a --without-pqsql option or something?

Comment: well the usual idea is to run the configure script and then make, make install. :) I haven't done any linux administration, so I'm not an expert on that!

Answer (score 0):

What distro are you on? You can probably reinstall the package that ships it.

It shouldn't be a big deal to reinstall packages in any case, most distros will properly keep all your configuration.

Comment: its shared hosting on CentOS 4.6